# tensorflow exception: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, word-embedding

I try to train with the data of the "BBC News archive". So the sequences to train with have the following shape: training sequences: (1780, 120), validation sequences: (445, 120)

The labels have the following shape: labels training: (1780, 1)
labels validation: (445, 1)

My model summary looks like this (I only want to get the 5 most frequent labels):

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_2 (Embedding)     (None, 120, 16)           16000     
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling1d_2   (None, 16)               0         
 (GlobalAveragePooling1D)                                        
                                                                 
 dropout_4 (Dropout)         (None, 16)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 512)               8704      
                                                                 
 dropout_5 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 2565      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 27,269
Trainable params: 27,269
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I try to fit it I get the following exception:

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible

The model is created with Keras:

```
*model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, input_length = maxlen),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation ='sigmoid')
    ])

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy']) *``
```

Has anyone an idea what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your prediction layer has 5 units while you have only 1 label for each data sample. There is a clear mismatch there. Replace your last layer:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation ='sigmoid')
```

with this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation ='sigmoid')
```

This should at least help you with the shape mismatch issue.

**Additional:**
From the shape of your labels and your final activation function (= `sigmoid`), I'm assuming you are performing a binary classification task. In that case, your loss function needs to be changed with the following:

```
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: So I found the solution, I must use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" instead of "categorical_crossentropy"

Comment: So, I assume you are doing multi-class classification. In that case in the final layer, instead of using `sigmoid`, you should use `softmax` as the activation function.